# How to autofill a text field when pressing a key

Tags: javascript, html, keypress, onkeypress

So I have a requirement where I need to type something and then halfway through, it should automatically fill the rest of the things.

## Example

I have a Text Field, where I start to type "col" then after I press space the text field should show me "column", auto for the auto-correct system.

Also, I was wondering if this could be implemented as an array or a column of data coming from my DB?

I made something like this, but this changes values of an innerHTML field. I need this for the text field itself.

```js
function handle(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Column";
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
</form>
```

I'm new to this so any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: get data from array or db and use jquery autosuggest .

Comment: Plugin is already there for this..https://github.com/atmb4u/AutoJS.. just change words in array

Comment: and if you have to make then here is some flow: on keyup get current word and according to that find in your array by contains() n get list of it

Comment: Please next time u ask a question dont change the whole question just ask it right in one submit. Thanks

Comment: im sorry but,i didnt change anything @Jessedegans

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs @Suchit

Comment: will try that @debin :)

Comment: @Venky If you like to use a native solution without using external libraries xheck my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your values from your database in a `JSON` and use the `e.target` property that will contain the `HTML` element where the `event` occurred.

Try the following code:

```js
// load your values from DB here
var dictionary = {
  'col': 'Column',
  'ro': 'Row',
  'tab': 'Table'
};

function handle(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (val in dictionary) {
      if (e.target.value == val) {
        e.target.value = dictionary[val];
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  jquery Auto suggest: Visit [HERE](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: For the record he changed his question so at first my answer wasnt wrong but indeed for this "new" question this is the right answer

Comment: @Jessedegans maybe i did not see the initial question.

Comment: i know haha but just to let u know :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs,but this shows a selection to make right ??,i want something where it would be automatically be replaced with a keyword,is that possible ??

Comment: @Venky without any event? i don't think so.

Comment: event is fine,lets say i press "Space" or "Enter",but i don't want a selection to be made,it should be replaced instantly when i press lets say "Space" or "Enter"

Comment: @Venky there can be multiple records for a substring so i guess you can hover on any of it and press inter in that case it should work.

Comment: I sorta made it to work for a single word and text field,but i get your point ,need to find a way for handling an array now or a whole column of data

Answer (score 0):

You must research **autocomplete**. Which you use language  for web development ?

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: autocomplete shows a selection,but i don't want to select ,i just want the input to be automatically be replaced with a word of my choice when i enter something

Comment: Which you use language for web development ? Just Html css static files ? Is Have a database MSSQL , MYSQL vs  ?

Comment: have a MSSQL db

Comment: Hi @Venky, i can't find text complete in input. I finded textcomplete plugin jquery text area in dropdown. https://yuku-t.com/textcomplete/ Sorry for that